# java web app configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration-files

I have a very basic question about web applications. I decided to ask on forum, because I don't exactly know, what to look for in google, I mean, i don't what key words should I use. 
I read about maven and ant but I still don't understand some things. This is my project structure:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/projectstructure.png/

I don't have any build.xml(for ant) or pom.xml(for maven) files, but anyway my project is properly running at my local computer. How is it possible if there are no configuration files ? I have only applicationContext.xml which is responsible for spring configuration, faces-config.xml for jsf 2.0 configuration and web.xml for servlet configuration. I tried to deploy it at openshift.com in this way: I exportet my project to .war file, and just commited and pushed it on server. The push ended well, but it does not work. Anyway I have to understand the basics of how my project works localy. Please give me any tips,  where should I start. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good wiki post about how to deploy a Java EE app on openshift:

http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2011/08/deploy-java-ee-application-on-openshift.html?m=1

It should put you on the right track.

Comment: thank you for quick reply and post, but what about my missing build.xml/pom.xml files ?